# NativeScript installation issue on MAC

Tags: macos, nativescript

Trying to install NativeScript on MAC machine, ran following command:

```
npm install -g nativescript
```

Installation fails with following error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3677839881'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.3677839881']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.3677839881' }
```

Would appreciate help to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a permission error, have you tried `sudo npm install -g nativescript` and entering your password? This will give the command root user (admin) privileges, as these are required to install global npm modules by default.

There is another approach, which is to change the global npm folder so it doesn't require elevated privileges:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped :-)